# Detect image visible pixels fits into boundaries

Tags: kineticjs

On example below image is rectangle, but some of it's pixels are transparent, I'd like to detect: are all not transparent pixels located inside white rectangle?

[image]

Is it possible with help of some kineticjs methods?

Comment: Google: html canvas context.getImageData.  You can get an array of all the RGBA pixel values on the canvas.  Then you can look for the alpha value to see which pixels are transparent.

Comment: @markE it is pure canvas method, I just tought there is something in KineticJS for such purposes.

Comment: Nope...KineticJS does not expose the context.getImageData method.